# Azure REST API: Network Security Group / Network Interface

Tags: rest, azure

I am trying to build a proof-of-concept integration with Azure Cloud into another system. I am not an Azure subject matter expert, so I am struggling with the end-to-end integration.

I am having trouble associating a "Network Security Group" to the "Network Interface". I am able to create both, but they do not not associate to each other until I manually go into the Cloud Portal and associate.

I am using the following:
API Documentation: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines

API Explorer: 
https://resources.azure.com

I am calling the following end-points in order:

publicIPAddresses
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionID}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/{resourceName}?api-version=2018-07-01

networkInterfaces
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionID}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/{resourceName}?api-version=2018-07-01

networkSecurityGroups
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionID}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/{resourceName}?api-version=2018-07-01

virtualMachines : https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionID}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{resourceName}?$expand=instanceView&api-version=2018-06-01

Everything else works except the NSG associating to the NIC.

Within the "networkSecurityGroups" message, I pass in the following parameter under the properties node.

```
"networkInterfaces": [{
        "id": "/subscriptions/" + subscriptionID + "/resourceGroups/" + resourceGroup + "/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/" + networkInterfaces
    }
]
```

I've tried reversing it by referencing the NSG in the Interface REST call, but still doesn't work. Oddly enough, I use the same syntax to associate the Interface to the VM itself, and that works as expected. Variations of the same syntax work with associating the PublicIP to the Interface, disks to VM, ect.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pretty sure you need to add this under NIC properties section:

```
"networkSecurityGroup": {
      "id": "NSG_Resource_Id"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Not sure why this didn't before, but I reversed the creation order, and added this node and it worked.

Comment: yeah, NIC needs to be created after NSG